# Connection Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for localhost.dbname=myblog failed: No such host is known

Tags: database, php-7.2

`This is my code:`

```
<?php
class Database {

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = 'myblog';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $conn;


public function connect() {
    $this->conn = null;

    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . '.dbname=' . $this->db_name,
         $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection Error:' .$e->getMessage();
    }
    return $this->conn;
}
}
```

`And this what did they say`

```
Connection Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for localhost.dbname=myblog failed: No such host is known. <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\Users\agadir\Downloads\xampp3\htdocs\API project\Models\post.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\agadir\Downloads\xampp3\htdocs\API project\API\POST\read.php(18): Post-&gt;read()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Users\agadir\Downloads\xampp3\htdocs\API project\Models\post.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

[CRUD operation with PDO Database Connection](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/crud-with-php-data-objects/)

**My suggestion:**

you can establish a database connection using PDO by creating a new instance of the `Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface` interface.

**Here's an example of how to establish a database connection using PDO in Magento 2:**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

// Inject the ResourceConnection object into your class constructor
public function __construct(ResourceConnection $resourceConnection)
{
    $this->connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
}

// Use the getConnection() method to get the PDO object
public function getConnection()
{
    return $this->connection;
}

// Example query using PDO
public function executeQuery()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
    $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}
```

In this example, the `ResourceConnection` object is injected into the constructor of your class. This object provides access to the database connection via the `getConnection()` method.

You can then use the `getConnection()` method to retrieve the PDO object, which can be used to execute SQL queries.

Note that Magento 2 also provides a query builder interface `(Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface)` that can be used to build SQL queries in a more structured way. However, using PDO directly may be necessary in certain situations where more fine-grained control over the SQL query is required.